# VLC : which file to update VLC Lua youtube script on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, lua, vlc

I am trying to read a youtube video through VLC on my mac:

```
 /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -v  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afzmwAKUppU&app=desktop
```

Which gives errors :

```
VLC media player 3.0.
8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)

[00007faf5b5e9140] lua generic warning: Error while running script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/extensions/youtube.lua, function descriptor() not found
[00007faf5b4589c0] macosx interface warning: Failed to enable media key support, likely app needs to be whitelisted in Security Settings.
[00007faf5b784950] securetransport tls client warning: Ignoring ALPN request due to lack of support in the backend. Proxy behavior potentially undefined.
[00007faf5b770200] lua stream warning: Couldn't extract video URL, falling back to alternate youtube API
[00007faf5b6b5b60] securetransport tls client warning: Ignoring ALPN request due to lack of support in the backend. Proxy behavior potentially undefined.
[00007faf5f97ce70] securetransport tls client warning: Ignoring ALPN request due to lack of support in the backend. Proxy behavior potentially undefined.
2020-10-15 13:45:28.281 VLC[65658:198319] Can't find app with identifier com.spotify.client
[00007faf5b5d8580] lua stream error: Couldn't extract youtube video URL, please check for updates to this script
[00007faf5b44b570] main playlist: playlist is empty
```

The youtube.lua, I got it by downloading the file from internet :

```
curl "http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/extensions/youtube.lua
```

Which works on my ubuntu, but not in my Mac: I am wondering if this is not the correct version for Mac OS. And so, which file should be put there ?
If I look on the VLC Lua directory, I find :

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/extensions$ ls -l
total 192
-rw-r--r--@ 1 romain  admin    72K Aug 14  2019 VLSub.luac
-rw-r--r--  1 root    admin    22K Oct 15 13:35 youtube.lua
```

the youtube.lua is the new script I added, but maybe it was another one to put there ?

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit late here now, but in any case:
You need to take the `youtube.lua` from here: https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua

Then rename it to `youtube.luac` and place it in the directory (for MacOS) `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/playlist`

I would recommend renaming the old one and keeping it in case something goes awry.

At least on my computer this worked and I can now open YouTube videos in VLC again.

Comment: This worked great for me. I was nervous about the name change and potentially format problems, but it fixed my YouTube issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 3.0.11.1 release? https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.11.1/macosx/vlc-3.0.11.1.dmg

You're correct that youtube.lua would be the correct file, though the issue might come from other parts of the code depending on it. FYI, since you are running a stable VLC build, the code you should look at is https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-3.0/-/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua.

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua is nightly v4 unstable builds (though for the lua script, they are identical).

Additionally, look out for a new release with an updated script soon https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2020-October/139076.html