# VLC : Couldn't extract youtube video URL / youtube.luac

Tags: lua, vlc

Following my question here : [VLC : which file to update VLC Lua youtube script on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371053/vlc-which-file-to-update-vlc-lua-youtube-script-on-mac-os-x)

I bumped again today about the infamous message : " lua stream error: Couldn't extract youtube video URL, please check for updates to this script"

Obviously I did follow what was working a year ago, but it doesn't work.
Anyone having the same issue ?

[image]

Comment: please paste text instead of pictures next time

Comment: regarding the error, you can blame google for this

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/27529

Answer (score 0):

do you still have this issue?
i use follow youtube.luac
https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua

I have renamed the old one and created a new one with notepad++ with the 1115 line from github and saved it in the vlc\lua\playlist folder.
Hope this will solve your problem :-)